# How do I parse a String to Time in Crystal Lang?

Tags: crystal-lang

I have a String in `MM-DD-YYYY` format such as: 04-08-2022.

I want to parse that to a Time type.

How do I do that in Crystal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crystal has a `Time.parse` ([documentation link](https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.4.0/Time.html#parse%28time%3AString%2Cpattern%3AString%2Clocation%3ALocation%29%3ATime-class-method)) method which can be used in this scenario.

The method receives a String argument to parse along with a String pattern argument and the requested Location of the time. Here is the method signature below.

```
def self.parse(time : String, pattern : String, location : Location) : Time
```

For your example, we could use the formatter to provide our custom format as `%m-%d-%Y`, where `%m` means month MM format, `%d` means day DD format, and `%Y` means YYYY format. Finally we use the local Location of the script being run.

For example:

```
time = Time.parse("04-08-2022", "%m-%d-%Y", Time::Location.local)
```